# cannot convert `char (*)[((unsigned int)((int)Tlength))]' to `char**

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/passing-2d-arrays)

I have a question in my codes. Can anyone help me?

```
void print(char S[], char * * path, int i, int j) {
    if (i == 0 || j == 0) return;
    if (path[i][j] == 'c') {
        print(S, path, i - 1, j - 1);
        cout << S[i];
    }
    else if (path[i][j] == 'u') print(S, path, i - 1, j);
    else print(S, path, i, j - 1);
}
int LongestCommonSubsequence(char S[], char T[]) {
    int Slength = strlen(S);
    int Tlength = strlen(T); /* Starting the index from 1 for our convinience (avoids handling special cases for negative indices) */
    int i, j;
    char path[Slength][Tlength];
    int common[Slength][Tlength];
    for (i = 0; i <= Tlength; i++) {
        common[0][i] = 0;
    } /*common[i][0]=0, for all i because there are no characters from string T*/
    for (i = 0; i <= Slength; i++) {
        common[i][0] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= Slength; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= Tlength; j++) {
            if (S[i] == T[j]) {
                common[i][j] = common[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                path[i][j] = 'c';
            }
            else if (common[i - 1][j] >= common[i][j - 1]) {
                common[i][j] = common[i - 1][j];
                path[i][j] = 'u';
            }
            else {
                common[i][j] = common[i][j - 1];
                path[i][j] = 'l';
            }

        }
    }
    print(S, path, Slength, Tlength); // it gives an Error!!!!
    return common[Slength][Tlength];

}
```

My error is in:

```
print(S,path,Slength,Tlength);
```

And It gives:

> cannot convert ``char (*)[((unsigned int)((int)Tlength))]``` ' to \``char** ```' for argument `2' to ``void print(char*, char**, int, int)'`

What should I do?

Comment: `path` decays into a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: You've assumed that `char[W][H]` decays into `char**`, which is not at all true. They're not even compatible.

Comment: Well, I *can* downvote you. Because "Giant Wall'o'Code" isn't a valid question and you show no effort to solving your own problem.

Comment: This is C++ right? I always thought forward-sizing a declared fixed array, `char path[Slength][Tlength]` was a C-thing only. Does this wall even compile??

Comment: It is C only, that's why I re-tagged it.

Comment: Upvoted just to counter-balance @DeadMG 's downvote.  :-)

Comment: @DeadMG: Unless you **know** what language the compiler is set to, retagging is wrong.  People copy C code into C++ programs all the time, and the `c++` tag is correct for such questions.

Comment: I don't know why people downvote gawky beginner questions so quickly without leaving any comment?!? The OP shows a bit too much code here to boil down to the real problem, but that's at least no reason to downvote without minimally pointing this out!!!

Comment: Retagged with C++ again until the OP is going to be explicit on this point. @DeadMG I also think that retagging is wrong in this case ...

Comment: @Chimera: It is not your job to "undo" other people's right to vote. Please do not do this. Upvote only if you think that this is a "great" question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why? Doesn't Chimera has his own rights to vote as he thinks it's appropriate??

Comment: @g-makulik: Yes, according to the quality of the question. Not according to previous votes. He is voting for the question; he is not voting for DeadMG's voting for the question. In this case he explicitly said he upvoted "just" to counter-balance someone else's vote, which is patently wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm also upvoting donvoted questions sometimes, if I don't see a reasonable comment for the OP why the question was downvoted (see my 1st comment). Didn't see DeadMG's comment when I wrote it, but he just stated having retagged the question, not why he downvoted. I think at least some minimal tolerance, politeness and guidance should be followed for treating beginners, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: I upvoted because I don't think the question deserved to be down-voted. If the question deserved a downvote, in my opinion I would have down-voted as well. But I was just messing around with @DeadMG

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is my right to vote as I see fit. Period.

Comment: @Chimera: I never said it wasn't. I merely asked you from the bottom of my heart to vote democratically and refrain from breaking the system. Hover your mouse over the "upvote" button to see the meaning that the SO designers envisaged an "upvote" to have. Yes, you are free to ignore it. I'm asking you not to. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111782/is-it-permissible-to-counteract-a-harsh-downvote-with-an-upvote-on-someone-else

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit THX for the meta link, that explains a lot about your reasoning. May be it would be better to **require** a comment for up-/downvoting. The 'implicit' rules and reasonings are hard to see for beginners, and thus to improve quality of questions (and answers) ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I up-voted because I saw merit in the question. And as I said before, I was messing with DeadMG. I don't believe I've broken the spirit or intent of voting here.

Comment: @Chimera But I also see that just 'messing' with another user isn't a good reasoning to up-/downvote ...

Comment: Looks like we should move this discussion (why to up-/downvote) to chat or an appropriate meta topic ...

Comment: No need, I have nothing else to say.

Comment: @Chimera: OK. You said "Upvoted just to counter-balance DeadMG's downvote". If that's not actually true, then there is nothing to discuss here :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's correct. I later said I was messing with DeadMG and I voted on the merit of the question. I can see how this caused some confusion.

Comment: @Chimera: Well, in the same comment you also said "I upvoted because I don't think the question deserved to be down-voted" which is just the same thing, but let's just leave it here I guess. We know each other's position.

Comment: How can you pass char x[10][10] to a function expecting char **? I'm not seeing how this could work.

Comment: Change the function declaration to fit its needs ... ;-) @Chimera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
char path[Slength][Tlength];
int common[Slength][Tlength];
```

(where `Slength` and `Tlength` are non-constant expressions)

Variable-length arrays are illegal.  The C++ standard requires *constant integral expressions* for array bounds in declarations (in a `new[]` expression, the outermost bound can be variable).

Note to voters: The OP marked his question as C++, someone else changed the tags, no idea what compiler is actually in use.

Comment: So the second parameter type char ** is valid in this case?

Comment: This is not true in C++11 (or C99 and up).

Comment: @slavik262: C++11 introduced VLAs? That's news to me. And `char**` is _still_ not compatible.

Comment: @slavik262 no, C++11 doesn't have VLAs. Only C99 and up does.

Comment: Ah, [it's a g++ extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594242/713961). My apologies.

Comment: And FWIW, C11, kind of removed VLAs: they are optional now.

Answer (score 0):

As **some** the commenters already mentioned `char [][]` (as `char[]`, or `char [][][]`, ... also would) decays to `char *` if passed to a function.

So to actually **solve** the problem with your code, just change

```
void print(char S[], char * * path, int i, int j)
```

to be

```
void print(char S[], char * path, int i, int j)
```