# C++ Switch case with string argument

Tags: c++, string, case

**Howdy guys,**

*so i am trying to use Case operation on a String ,is Case operators only works with Integers ?
Because the compiling error :*

```
switch quantity not an integer
```

*And i have this code as an example :*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main(){
string type;
cout<<"Please enter your computer type (PC ,Laptop, Smartphone) : "<<endl;
getline(cin, type);

 switch(type){

case "PC":
 cout<<"Ok so you'vr got a "<<type;
 break;

case "Laptop":
 cout<<"Aha ,u got a "<<type;
 break;

case "Smartphone":
 cout<<"That s not bad ,u ve got :"<<type;
 break;
}


return 0;
}
```

I know that i can use other logical operators like IF ; but i am stydying the Case operators so i am curious can i work with Strings or not.

Comment: No, but you can switch on the hash of a string, which you can compute at compile time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19123540/179910

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c/c++ [`switch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement only operates on numeric integer primitives.

You cannot use it with `char*` pointers (literals).

> attr(optional) switch ( condition ) statement
>
> condition  -   any expression of integral or enumeration type, or of a class type with a conversion function to integral or enumeration type, or a declaration of a single non-array variable of such type with a brace-or-equals initializer.

Comment: thank you! sorry for my noob question

Comment: @user3602556 De nada! Welcome to SO. THX for the accept. In future research a bit more thoroughly before asking a question. You'll find that most problems already have answers here.