# Where does following array getting memory from?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

In function fun, I am allocating array A. The size of array is known at run time, I am wandering from which area A is getting memory. My wild guess is stack but I couldn't think of any reason for it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


void fun(int n)
{
   int A[n];

    //do something with array

   for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
     cout<<A[i]<<" ";
   cout<<"\n";

}

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n; 
  fun(n);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I hope you realize that VLA's (variable-length arrays) is a non-standard feature.

Comment: @user2030677 Yes, I do now.

Answer (score 4):

> "Where does following array getting memory from?"

From the function local stack of `fun()`.

**Note:**
Allocation of stack local arrays using a variable is a compiler (standards version) specific extension. The common term for the extension is VLA (variable length array) and is supported by several compilers (e.g. GCC g++), and also demanded by some c standard definitions.

See here for more clarifications please: [**Does C++ support Variable Length Arrays?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays)