# int[n][m], where n and m are known at runtime

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I often need to create a 2D array with width and height (let them be n and m) unknown at compile time, usually I write :

```
vector<int> arr(n * m);
```

And I access elements manually with :

```
arr[j * m + i]
```

I recently got told that I could instead write :

```
int arr[n][m] // n and m still only known at runtime.
```

So here are 2 questions :

1. Is this behaviour allowed by the C++ Standard ?
2. How should I pass such an array to a function ? g++ reports that arr has type `int (*)[n]`, but again, n is dynamic and not known outside the function where it is declared (`main`).

Comment: 1. No. 2. Does it matter if the answer to 1. is "no"?

Comment: It's non-standard behaviour (and you can change the compiler options to disallow non-standard behaviour). Do what you were doing with the vector, but just wrap it up in a class.

Comment: Or use `vector<vector<int>>`

Comment: The `vector` solution seems like the best one...

Comment: do your mean runtime or compile time in the title and`// n and m still only known at runtime.`, since you write `with width and height (let them be n and m) unknown at compile time, usually I write :`?

Comment: @juanchopanza in c++14, the answer to 1. is Yes

Comment: Both in title and non-standart code snippet i mean a runtime.

Comment: @cdkrot it's like jxhs answer, but it has found its way into c++14 standard

Comment: @Quest Are you sure of that? Do you have a quote?

Comment: @juanchopanza I've seen it in one answer here, but i can't find a link.

Comment: @Quest I am not sure it has gone in, but if it has, I don't think it supported 2D arrays where both sizes are unknown at compile time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ye probably not but i can be wrong

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The feature you are asking about (where the dimensions are only made known at runtime) is a non-standard extension of C++, but a standard one of C.99 (made into an optional feature in C.11). The feature is called [variable-length array (VLA)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), and the link is the documentation for GCC.

If you are using GCC, then you are to pass the length of the array as a parameter to the function.

```
void foo (int m, int arr[][m]) {
    //...
}
```

***However***, there seems to be a bug in either the compiler or the documentation, as the above function prototype syntax only works when compiling C code, not C++ (as of gcc version 4.8.2). The only work-around I found was to use a `void *` parameter, and cast it int the function body:

```
int foo_workaround (int m, void *x)
{
    int (*arr)[m] = static_cast<int (*)[m]>(x);
    //...
}
```

There are other solutions if you do not want to rely on a compiler extension. If you don't mind a separate allocation for each row, you can use a vector of vectors, for example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > arr(n, std::vector<int>(m));
```

However, if you want a single allocation block like you demonstrated in your own example, then it is better to create a wrapper class around `vector` to give you 2-d like syntax.

```
template <typename T>
class vector2d {

    int n_;
    int m_;
    std::vector<T> vec_;

    template <typename I>
    class vector2d_ref {
        typedef std::iterator_traits<I> TRAITS;
        typedef typename TRAITS::value_type R_TYPE;
        template <typename> friend class vector2d;
        I p_;
        vector2d_ref (I p) : p_(p) {}
    public:
        R_TYPE & operator [] (int j) { return *(p_+j); }
    };

    typedef std::vector<T> VEC;
    typedef vector2d_ref<typename VEC::iterator> REF;
    typedef vector2d_ref<typename VEC::const_iterator> CREF;

    template <typename I> 
    vector2d_ref<I> ref (I p, int i) { return p + (i * m_); }

public:

    vector2d (int n, int m) : n_(n), m_(m), vec_(n*m) {}
    REF operator [] (int i) { return ref(vec_.begin(), i); }
    CREF operator [] (int i) const { return ref(vec_.begin(), i); }

};
```

The wrapper's `operator[]` returns an intermediate object that also overloads `operator[]` to allow 2-dimensional array syntax when using the wrapper.

```
    vector2d<int> v(n, m);
    v[i][j] = 7;
    std::cout << v[i][j] << '\n';
```

Comment: I am using g++, the compilations failing for me (using -std=c++11) for following functions (here just prototypes): int sum(int n, int[][n] m); int sum(int n, int[n][n] m); Reason: "use of parameter outside function body before ] token". What is wrong?

Comment: Try `-std=gnu++11` instead.

Comment: I am not sure I am reading your code correctly. What do you have an extra 'm' before the ')'?

Comment: m means "matrix", the name of array.

Comment: Oh, not. Moving arr name before [][n] doesn't fixed.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the documentation for passing to functions only works for C code, not for C++ code. It is either a compiler bug or documentation bug.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I filed a bug on gcc's bugzilla, i will write you, when they answer.

Comment: @cdkrot: You are very welcome. This is likely because there is no C++ mangling conventions for a VLA argument, so the C++ front end refuses to accept the syntax. Wrapping the function around an `extern "C"` didn't help either, though, so there might be room to fix something.

Comment: Regarding VLA and C++ proper, [see this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8593643/315052).

Answer (score 2):

Why not have an `std::vector` of `std::vector`'s?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > arr(n, std::vector<int>(m));
```

Accessing an item then becomes:

```
std::cout << "(2,1) = " << arr[2][1] << std::endl;
```

Comment: It is not simple 2D array, it is an array of array. But this solution is also acceptable.

Comment: @Jost, if you declare int a[10][10] it will be, internally, int a[100]

Comment: @cdkrot please see the first answer on [***this question***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565039/how-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-formatted-in-memory)

Comment: yes, that is what i talking about, that the elements are stored in contigious array. About passing in function, answer one on this question should work, but i haven't tested yet.

Comment: @cdkrot the `std::vector` of `std::vector`'s will act the same way. Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: I haven't downvoted anybody, std::vector will use dynamic memory allocation and it will not act this way, it will be like array, containing pointers to other arrays (which may be in other place)

Comment: @cdkrot you're entirely right, I misspoke. Good call. Also, that second part wasn't directed at you :)

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector` of `std::vector`'s (from `#include <vector>`) would do the same thing as a 2-Dimensional array:

```
int n = 10, m = 10; //vector dimensions
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n, std::vector<int>(m)); //Create 2D vector (vector will be stored as "std::vector<int> arr(n * m);

//you can get values from 2D vector the same way that you can for arrays
int a = 5, b = 5, value = 12345;
arr[a][b] = 12345;
std::cout << "The element at position (" << a << ", " << b << ") is " << arr[a][b] << "." << std::endl;
```

outputs:

`The element at position (5, 5) is 12345.`