# How to return a matrix from a function, in c?

Tags: c

My c code for matrix addition is given below:

```
mat(int n,int a[][5],b[][5] ){
   int i,c[5][5];

   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
       for(j=0;j<5;j++)
           c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];

    return c;
}
```

When I compile this my compiler caught error:

```
||warning: command line option '-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\retuturn_a_matrix.c|2|warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\retuturn_a_matrix.c|2|warning: no previous declaration for 'mat' [-Wmissing-declarations]|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\retuturn_a_matrix.c||In function 'mat':|
C:\Users\Amir Khasru\Desktop\retuturn_a_matrix.c|8|error: return makes integer from pointer without a cast|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: In your program there are many other errors that are not related to your question. Start correcting them first.

Answer (score 2):

This is your code (just formatted and added a missing closing brace):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

mat(int n, int a[][5], b[][5] )
{
    int i, c[5][5];

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<5; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

I compile with:
`$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow test.c -o test` and first thing I get is:

```c
test.c:3:24: error: unknown type name ‘b’
 mat(int n, int a[][5], b[][5] )
```

Let's fix that (add `int` before `b` and `j`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

mat(int n, int a[][5], int b[][5] )
{
    int i, c[5][5];

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Now we get:

```
test.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 mat(int n, int a[][5], int b[][5] )
 ^
test.c: In function ‘mat’:
test.c:11:10: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   return c;
          ^
test.c:11:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
test.c:3:9: warning: unused parameter ‘n’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 mat(int n, int a[][5], int b[][5] )
         ^
test.c:13:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

So what to we get:

- `mat()` returns `int` because it's a default fallback that dates to before C99, but no *is not standard anymore*. It seems though, that you are compiling on Visual Studio which basically implements C89 + some C99 for C++ compatibility -- but still, fix it.
- Then you return `c`, which is definitely not of type `int`.
- Also you don't use `n`, I guess it's meant to be the number of rows?
- You return after the first inner loop is done -- that's probably not wanted.

What to do instead:
Generally you usually want the caller to give space for the result, as you return `c` which is local to `mat()` it is undefined behavior what happens after `mat()` finishes. Instead use the following declaration for `mat()`:

```c
void mat(int r, int c, int m1[r][c], int m2[r][c], int mr[r][c]);
```

where `r` is rows, `c` is columns, `m1`, `m2` are the input matrices, `mr` is the result matrix.

The code would then be:

```c
void mat(int r, int c, int m1[r][c], int m2[r][c], int mr[r][c])
{
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                        mr[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j];
                }
        }
}
```

You do not need to return anything -- you write to an object the caller provided (hopefully). If you feel brave you can check for `m1 == NULL || m2 == NULL || mr == NULL` before.

Let's see how this works using this test code:

```c
void print_mat(int r, int c, int m[r][c]);

int main() {
        int m1[2][5] = {
                {0,1,2,3,4},
                {1,2,3,4,5}
        };
        int m2[2][5] = {
                {10,11,12,13,14},
                {11,12,13,14,15}
        };

        printf("printing matrix m1:\n");
        print_mat(2,5,m1);
        printf("printing matrix m1:\n");
        print_mat(2,5,m2);

        int c[2][5];
        mat(2,5,m1,m2,c);

        printf("printing matrix m1+m2:\n");
        print_mat(2,5,c);
}

void print_mat(int r, int c, int m[r][c])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                        printf("\t%d", m[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        return;
}
```

I get:

```
printing matrix m1:
        0       1       2       3       4
        1       2       3       4       5
printing matrix m1:
        10      11      12      13      14
        11      12      13      14      15
printing matrix m1+m2:
        10      12      14      16      18
        12      14      16      18      20
```

which is exactly what it's supposed to be.

In the end:

- State the types specifically, it helps.
- Turn on all warnings if you are unsure.
- *Usually* don't acquire memory in a subfunction, let the caller do this.
- If you are unsure with pointers/arrays, try to avoid them and write small understandable test-cases; do research!

Comment: I love this syntax. Did not know is possible `void print_mat(int r, int c, int m[r][c]);`

Comment: @Nick Yep it's nice; just be sure to have `r` and `c` in the declaration before the array using it!

Comment: is this original C99 or C11 ?

Comment: @Nick pretty sure C99, I compile with `-std=c99` and I've used it on many compilers, some of which at least don't support all of C11.

Comment: I found why I don't know this syntax - this is C99.  
C++ can not compile this.
`x.cc:3:31: error: use of parameter outside function body before ‘]’ token
 void test(int const n, int a[n]){`

Comment: `[nmmm@zenbook asyncore_cpp]$ gcc x.c -std=c89 -Wpedantic
x.c:3:1: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Wvla]
 void test(int const n, int a[n]){`

Comment: @Nick Yep, apparently it's a feature of C99, made optional in C11 (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551779/intnm-where-n-and-m-are-known-at-runtime). Also it ain't in C++ O.o

Answer (score -1):

You can pass by reference.

I can not do it with your matrix, because I don't think code is 100% correct. Code would look like this.

```
int mat(int x, int y, const int *m_a, const int *m_b, int *m_out);
```

where:

- int that function returns is kind of status code.
- x and y are width and height of the matrix.
- m_a, m_b are the input matrix. they are const.
- m_out is the output matrix.

You can "upgrade" the function by return the matrix like this:

```
int *mat(int x, int y, const int *m_a, const int *m_b, int *m_out){
    // do some work
    if (something is not OK)
        return NULL;
    else
        return m_out;
}

// in main()
int a[5 * 6];
int b[5 * 6];
int result[5 * 6];
mat(5, 6, a, b, result);
// use result.
```

Third option, probably worse one - allocate the memory, and return allocated memory. Later memory needs to be freed.

```
int *mat(int x, int y, const int *m_a, const int *m_b){
    int *m_out = malloc( x * y * sizeof int);

    if (m_out == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // do some work

    if (something is not OK){
        free(m_out);
        return NULL;
    }else
        return m_out;
}

// in main()
int *m = mat(5, 6, a, b);
// use m
free(m);
```

Comment if you have question.

In all examples, I assume single dimension array. You can easily translate two dimension coordinates into single dimension, check here:

[How to map the indexes of a matrix to a 1-dimensional array (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015556/how-to-map-the-indexes-of-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-c)

Here are complete, working example made the way I would do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *mat(int x, int y, const int *m_a, const int *m_b, int *m_out){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < x * y; ++i)
        m_out[i] = m_a[i] + m_b[i];

    return m_out;
}

void print_mat(int x, int y, const int *m){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < y; ++j)
            printf("| %4d ", m[i * y + j]);

        printf("|\n");
    }
}

#define X   2
#define Y   2

int main(){
    int a[X * Y] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int b[X * Y] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int result[X * Y];

    int *r = mat(X, Y, a, b, result);

    print_mat(X, Y, r);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the output:

```
[nmmm@zenbook HM3]$ gcc -Wall -Wpedantic x.c
[nmmm@zenbook HM3]$ ./a.out 
|    2 |    4 |
|    6 |    8 |
[nmmm@zenbook HM3]$
```

Comment: Why -1? I don't see any problems with my code

Comment: Not my downvote, but `int a[5, 6];` is wrong. The function arguments can still be fixed-size arrays as in the OP if that's all that's needed, although making them a pointer+size does make things more generic.

Comment: typo, fixed. This is why you need typedefs, but I decided not to add confusion.

Comment: Ok, now it even compiles. (homework done for free)

Comment: Hey Nick, can I declare variable dimension array in c.... like "int array[n][n]?"

Comment: yes, pls check the other answer from larkey. In my way I try to do it as generic as possible, with one dimension array