# Why Does the New C++ Standard use "ISO/IEC 14882:2015"?

Tags: c++, c++14, iso

According to the [ISO Web Site](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=64029) the new standard is named "ISO/IEC 14882:**2015**" rather than "ISO/IEC 14882:**2014**". Why is that so and will that change? There are alreadly lots of things tagged C++14, for example.

In case you are interested in the technical content rather than the standard's document, it is available from [github](https://github.com/) from the [ISO C++ Repository](https://github.com/cplusplus) as [N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf).

Comment: In the abstract it's called "ISO/IEC 14882:2014", one of these must be a typo.

Comment: The standard was ratified in 2014, but it wasn't *published* then. Or was it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg .. I'm fairly sure that doesn't make a difference, or does it?

Comment: Anyway `__cplusplus` is defined to `201402L` (at least I hope it will be so in the official standard), so we can continue to call it C++14...

Comment: Admittedly, the oddity of the name provided an opportunity to create a question implicitly indicating that C++15 (or C++15) is released! :-)

Comment: Committee approved it in 2014, it was published in 2015

Comment: @BЈовић: well, if the standard name is "...2015" surely the revision will be referred to as "C++15". That's similar to C89 and C90.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Wait, that's the same thing? Always confused me

Comment: Here you can find http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012, previous version which is also named 2011 and 2012. I wonder if they will keep 60$ price

Comment: @Columbo: you mean C89 and C90? Yes, it is the same standard, also just affected by the publication date. See e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C).

Comment: Do you know whether [N4296](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4296.pdf) is still C++14, or whether it includes C++1z bits?

Comment: Also according to that text, C++14 is "based on the C programming language as described in ISO/IEC 9899:1999." News to me.

Comment: @marcinj: there is work being done to get ANSI to offer C++14 at a reasonable price (target: $30). That will take a while and there is no guarantee it will work.

Comment: @Angew: N4140 is the version matching C++14 (the official document is N4141 - easy to remember as 14 backwards).

Comment: If you check the link again, the typo has been corrected and it now reads 2014

Comment: C90 has different section numbering to C89

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It's true. C++03 was based on C90, for example. C++14 is based on C99. It's just a way of saying that the "underlying" C standard has also been updated and that newer C++ refers to the update.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you follow the link, ISO summarizes the C++ language by saying "C++ is a general purpose programming language based on the C programming language as described in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 *Programming languages : C*…" which is very misleading. C++ is based on AT&T C from the mid-80's, not C99. C++14 certainly isn't a superset of C99; C99 features such as VLAs and `restrict` are not present and there are dozens of little incompatibilities due to their divergence long ago.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Except, **by definition**, per the text you just quoted, C++14 is based on C99. Older incarnations of C++ may have been based on mid-80s AT&T C, but C++98 was based on C89, C++11 was based on C99, and C++14 is based on C99. It's an irrefutable fact. Perhaps you're confusing "is based on" with "is a superset of"? The former does not mean the latter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is there a `lang rebase` command I don't know about? ISO's commentary is not normative. There is [intro.refs] §1.2 but that's not what the synopsis there is talking about. It's an irrefutable fact that C++14 is not a superset of any edition of ISO C.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: And nobody is claiming that it is. That all being said, don't worry: [it's not just you](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8593643/560648). :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ISO is strongly suggesting that it is, if you follow the link and actually read what it says there. Anyway, this discussion is a bit silly because nobody should read that synopsis as their introduction to C++ anyway.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Think of it this way. You and I are based on monkeys. Doesn't mean we _must_ have hair all over. (And please tone it down; you're coming across somewhat accusatory all of a sudden with your "actually read" etc! Did you not spot that what it "actually" says there was written by, um, _me_?)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit We are based on monkeys, not orangutans. Saying C++14 is based on C99 is like saying homo sapiens are based on orangutans. They're different, contemporary branches. Sorry for any disturbance, it's my bedtime. Nites!

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The truth is you are at odds with the official ISO definition of the language and, like, everyone else :P If you have your own definition of "based on" then that's fine but doesn't mean ISO or anyone else has to share it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Update: The title has been adjusted and now reads ...:2014

---

<sub><joke> Obviously the postfix-increment finally showed its side-effect </joke></sub>

I suppose the person responsible for publishing this article must have made a typo, as every other source mentioning it uses ISO/IEC 14882:201**4**, and so does the text that follows the title:

> ISO/IEC 14882:2014 specifies requirements for implementations of the
> C++ programming language.

Also consider this passage from ["We have C++14!"](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/08/we-have-cpp14):

> We will perform some final editorial tweaks, on the order of fixing a
> few spelling typos and accidentally dropped words, and then transmit
> the document to ISO **for publication this year as the brand new
> International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) Programming Language C++,
> a.k.a. C++14.**

C++14 was **ratified** in 2014, hence the name. However, if the **publication** did only happen this January - i.e. in 2015 - then there is a chance that this is more than just a typo. Then the name ISO/IEC 14882:2014 was mentioned solely in anticipation of the publishing still happening in 2014.
According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization),

> These are designated using the format *ISO[/IEC] [/ASTM] [IS]
> nnnnn[-p]:[yyyy] Title*, where *nnnnn* is the number of the standard,
> *p* is an optional part number, ***yyyy* is the year published**, and *Title* describes the subject.

Though even if the official name of the standard document will indeed be corrected to 2015 as the publishing year, we would still call it C++14 as the final document was basically established last year (and also because introducing "C++15" at this point would cause a lot of irritation, as with ISO C89/C90).

Comment: The isocpp post (or somewhere else) mentions that it should be 2014 in the title.

Comment: Stefanus du Toit (C++14 editor) at least believes it's an error on the ISO page: ["C++14 is officially published! http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=64029 … (and yes, the ":2015" should read ":2014")"](https://twitter.com/stefanusdutoit/status/555430491948457984).

Comment: If you check the link again, the typo has been corrected and it now reads 2014