# How to make user input declare the size of string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

something like

```
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (myfile,line) )
            {
                nr++; //how many lines in a text file
            }
        }

string y[nr] = {};
```

only works when I specify actual number like y[10].

Comment: std::vector<std::string>> y;

Comment: The user cannot "declare" the array. Only the programmer can.

Comment: Related: [Does C++ support Variable Length Arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8593643/608639) and [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/608639) The latter probably makes this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot declare arrays with an unknown size unless you are using a non portable compiler extension.  The standard way to accomplish this is to use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

```
int x;
cout << "Size of your array: ";
cin >> x;
vector<string> y(x);
```

Comment: Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99. As an extension, GCC accepts variable-length arrays as a member of a structure or a union. See GCC's [6.19 Arrays of Variable Length](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: @jww Thanks for mentioning that.  Since it was tagged as c++ I didn't want to mention C99.