# define array with unsure size

Tags: c++, arrays

As I understand it, when we define an array like `const char argv[SIZE];` "SIZE" must be a number which is known at compile time.

But recently I read AOSP code, and found this: http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/system/netd/server/NetdConstants.cpp#70

```
static int execIptables(IptablesTarget target, bool silent, va_list args) {
    /* Read arguments from incoming va_list; we expect the list to be NULL terminated. */
    std::list<const char*> argsList;
    argsList.push_back(NULL);
    const char* arg;
    do {
        arg = va_arg(args, const char *);
        argsList.push_back(arg);
    } while (arg);

    int i = 0;
    const char* argv[argsList.size()];
    ...
```

It seems that `const char* argv[argsList.size()];` uses a size which is only known at runtime. Is this because this array is defined in a function which will allocate the array in the stack or because the compiler can figure out what the size is at compile time?

Comment: Some compilers support (as an extension) arrays on the stack with a size that is only known at runtime.

Comment: The author is expecting a non-standard feature (variable length arrays, VLAs) to be supported by whatever C++ compiler is building this code.

Comment: An `std::list` used to accumulate varargs then used to create a VLA and copy everything there? Who the hell wrote this garbage? I don't want to use this phone anymore...

Comment: @MatteoItalia Concur.  I would have just used `std::vector<const char*>` and thrown out *both* the `std::list` and the VLA.

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays

Comment: I have extensively edited the question to improve the English.  It was already perfectly understandable to a native speaker, but I hope this will help other non-native speakers read it.  If you feel I have mangled your question, please feel free to edit or revert my changes.

Comment: @MartinBonner English is not my mother language, go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct terminology is *variable-length-array* (VLA).

The C++ language standard does not support this feature.

The C language standard started supporting it at some point.

Allocation in memory is compiler-dependent (i.e., not dictated by the standard).

Comment: You should specify that, even if standard C++ doesn't support it, it's a common extension (supported by both gcc and clang).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: OK, good point. I was referring to the general standard of course. Your comment here will do this for me (since I'm not sure what other C++ compilers support this). Thank you :)

Comment: Gcc and clang, but *not* MSVC - which could be an issue depending on your target platforms.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I don't have specific information on every compiler out there (let alone, on every **future** compiler). That's why I preferred to keep this answer platform-agnostic. Anyone making use of it, should check their specific compiler.

Comment: Yes.  My preference is to avoid using extensions (except things which add extra compiler warnings like `__attribute__(format(printf))`, and which can be hidden behind #ifdef's).  Particularly when there's a perfectly good equivalent in C++ already:  `std::vector`.