# What are different ways of initializing the size of an array with user input in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, gcc, stl

I was wondering what are some alternatives to doing the following code snippet in c++.

```cpp
int i;
cin >> i;
int arr[i];
```

I have recently started looking into competitive programming and trying to learn more.

EDIT: For those comments about this not being cpp. It compiles successfully with the makefile I am using in my class which is using `gcc -std=c++11 -o a.exe main.cpp` and returns to the console when I input a length of 1

```cpp
array length: 1
```

Comment: You can also use something like this: `int number = 0; while (cin >> number) { myVector.push_back(number); }`, but, here, you are specifying the size directly.

Comment: This code snippet is not valid C++; many compilers allow variable-length arrays as an extension, but in standard C++ you need to know the size at compile time unless you want to mess with dynamic arrays using `new[]`.

Comment: *What are different ways...* -- The way you're showing us in the question isn't C++, so you can forget about the way you're showing us in your question.

Comment: Learn C++, then start competing.You are at a serious competitive disadvantage if you try to do it the other way around. [Here is a list of good references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: In CP I usually allocate all my arrays with fixed sizes set at the maximum specified in the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead in C++, e.g.

```
int i;
cin >> i;
std::vector<int> arr(i);
```

BTW: [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) is not supported by C++ standard. Also see [Variable Length Array (VLA) in C++ compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334435/3309790)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Don't know why the OP hasn't done so.

Comment: It seems like the code snippet above works because of my gcc version and not specifically the c++ [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - the OP probably won't accept the answer because of a mistaken belief that "gcc accepts his code with VLAs so the code is correct".

Comment: This is why I wished gcc (and other) compilers would turn the VLA option *off* by default.  Many new programmers have the mistaken belief that their "VLA" code is correct when it really isn't.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
int i = 0;

cin >> i;

auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(i); // #include <memory>
        // Or: std::make_shared<int[]>(i);
```

Another way is to use `std::vector`:

```
int i = 0;

cin >> i;

std::vector<int> arr(i); // #include <vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not C++. It uses a C language feature (from the C99 version of the C standard) called "variable-length arrays" - where arrays on the stack can have a length determined at run-time.

Variable-length arrays are considered are dangerous and considered a rather bad idea; see:

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

If you compile your code while telling the compiler to only accept standard-compliant code, it will fail: `gcc -std=c++11 -pedantic-error`. [Try it on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7ItHWu).

In C++ **the size of an array is set at compile-time**, period. Like other users suggested, you can use dynamic allocation to obtain a run-time-determined-length contiguous area in memory, of your choice of size: Using `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or even plain allocation with `new` (although the latter is not recommended).