# C++ - Passing 2D array to function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I am trying to pass a 2D array to a function but I am failing to do so. There is no problem with passing 1D array. How can I do this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void DisplayBoard(int matrix[],int n) // Prints out the given array.
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                    cout << matrix[j];
            }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int n,m;
        cin>>n;
        //int matrix[n]={};
        DisplayBoard(matrix,n);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: pleae show your code with the 2d array ([mcve])

Comment: `int matrix[n]={};` isn't valid c++ code anyways. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593643/does-c-support-variable-length-arrays) please.

Comment: int matrix[n]={}; - just fills it with zeros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to input index number (n) from user and then input array object from user too
i complete your code like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void DisplayBoard(int matrix[],int n) // Prints out the given array.
{ 
  cout<<endl ; 
     for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      {
              cout << matrix[j]<<" ";
       }
    }

     int main() {
       int n,m;
         cin>>n ; 
         int matrix[n];
  
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            cin>>matrix[i];
               } 
             DisplayBoard(matrix,n);
          return 0;
        }
```

remember to declare array in main function too ,
that was one of your code error !

and this is incorrect to declare array :

```
int matrix[n]={} // incorrect !
```

Comment: I used that as I said just to fill it with zeroes instead of making 2 for's to fill it.

Comment: ow , i just saw it now

Comment: try to declare array with pointer to passing to function  .  (int * matrix ) declare this in your function

Comment: and then when you want to pass matrix from main to your function use (int * ) before to declare your array in pointer

Comment: Oh, yeaah. That was it! Thanks. I have it done!

Answer (score 0):

```
Well. int matrix[n]={}; fills it with zeros and that's what I wanted to do. And my code with 1D array works fine but if I do it like so it does not.

    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DisplayMatrix(int matrix[][],int n,int m)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
                cout << matrix[j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int matrix[n][m]={};
    DisplayMatrix(matrix,n,m);
    return 0;
}
```